# (FLASK) I can't figure out why my html file doesn't update/render

Tags: python, web, flask, jinja2

I already tried clearing my browser cache and history, but that did not seem to help. The old html file I used (Jinja) doesn't seem to update.

Basically, I rendered a file before this and jinja seems to be rendering that old file (not sample or index) instead of either sample or index .html.

I'm a beginner at Flask, so if this is a simple fix I apologize I don't know much...

Here is my code:

**sample.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(" APP ")

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("sample.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**index.html** (inherits from sample.html)

```
{% extends "sample.html" %}
{% block title %}Home Page {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1> Welcome to the Index Page!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**sample.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
             <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item active">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to return `index.html` in your view (the home function) (not `sample.html`). Give that a try and if it didn't work make sure your sample.html is error free by removing the blocks and running it as is.

Comment: @Hossein that doesn't solve the issue. My old file is still cached and I can't update it.

Comment: Does Flask refer to previous caches if there are errors in HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I ran the file in another text editor and never ended the process (even though I closed that window). Just restarted my PC and problem solved.

Silly mistake, but I guess beginners learn? :D

Answer (score 0):

You should render `index.html`

```py
return render_template("index.html")
```

instead of `simple.html`, as `index.html` is extending `simple.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to render index.html file like this

````
def home():
    return render_template("index.html") ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Assuming passing `index.html` (instead of the template is extends) to `render_template()` doesn't resolve this, it may depend on how you're starting the app. If you're starting it via something other than

```
python sample.py
```

Then the `if __name__ == '__main__':` won't execute, and `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD` won't get set. Try setting `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD` right after you instantiate `Flask()`. (Also, for good form, remove the spaces on either side of APP.)

Comment: It still doesn't update the render :/ im so lost at this point

Comment: I just figured it out. I ran the file in another text editor and never ended the process (even though I closed that window). Just restarted my PC and problem solved. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: It happens. You're unlikely to make that mistake more than a few more times.

Comment: @CodingBoy maybe you want to answer your question here (which is: make sure you're not running the flask app in another terminal and that it's properly stopped) and set it as the accepted answer. People may not see your comment and keep posting in here to help you fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure html file is in templates folder.**
We use the render_template() method to render the index.html template which we'll be creating in the ***templates folder*** of our project and then you should render index.html.

```
return render_template("index.html")
```